# how to get the information of Phone Applicationpage while deactivating the application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

When i am deactivating my application,is there any way to find out the Last Phone Application Page ,such as name of the page ,its information on the deactivate method of App.xaml.cs while deactivating.

Answer (score 2):

First:
Each page can override [OnNavigatedFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method. And you can store important info into [ApplicationSettings](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-application-settings).

On [Application.Deactivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event handler you can read this info from settings.

Also, have a look at [this page](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Application-Lifecycle-and-Tombstoning). You can find there few usefull ideas.

Second: 
You can use [this trick](http://debugmode.net/2011/09/06/getting-url-of-current-page-in-windows-phone-dynamically-through-code/) to store the `Uri` of last page. So, you'll get page name and passed parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I  am  afraid the Application_Deactivated function can not tell you that infomation with its argument .

But I think you can keep a record of the lastest navigated to page's info in a global environment .